# How can I add text in my scroll to top button which already has an icon in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I'm totally new to this field so please help me out.

I've tried almost everything but nothing seems to be working. Actually, I want to add some text in my scroll to top button, which has already been made and working perfectly and it has an icon in it. But I want to add some text with that icon. Here's [a link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquee_tag.htm) what I want to do!

Following is the code I have in js file:

```
// Append Button
$("body").append($("<a />")
        .addClass("scroll-to-top")

            .attr({
                "href": "#",
                "id": "scrollToTop"
                            })
        .append(
            $("<i />")
            .addClass("icon icon-chevron-up icon-white")
    ));
```

where should I have to add the text, either in the above code file or into the code of my page?

Help of any kind would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post HTML code also or share fiddle.

Comment: This seems like overkill. You can simply created the anchor tag directly in the html without the need of having javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following.

```
$("body").append($("<a />")
    .addClass("scroll-to-top")

        .attr({
            "href": "#",
            "id": "scrollToTop"
                        })
    .append(
        $("<i>Scroll</i>")
        .addClass("icon icon-chevron-up icon-white")
));
```

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: I tried the above code, it's showing the text but not in single line.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you. I just edited the width of that button and now the text is in one line.

Comment: One more question, Can I duplicate the code to make another button like this. One with text and one with icon?

Comment: Yes you can but as Andrei P. mentioned in a comment to your question is it really needed to create these using javascript. You can add these in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
      } else {
      $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
     }
    });
    
    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
     $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
     }, 600);
     return false;
    });
    
   });
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.scrollup {
 width: 250px;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 display: block;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background-color: #6BAFBD;
 border:1px solid #6BAFBD;
 border-radius:10px;
 color:#fff;
}
.scrollup .middle{
 margin:12px;
}
.scrollup:hover{
 background-color: #BD8D6B;
 border:1px solid #BD8D6B;
 color:#000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Back To Top<i class = "fa fa-chevron-up middle"></i></a>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/5nsa9nvr/).