# Can't get my jquery anchor working on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll, anchor

I am trying to make an anchor that takes you to top of the page. It (somehow) works on mobile but it does not work on desktop. Is there a way I can fix this? Here is the code:

```
  <a class="anchor" href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>


$(document).ready(function() {

  // declare variable
 var scrollTop = $(".anchor");

$(window).scroll(function() {
// declare variable
var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();

// if user scrolls down - show scroll to top button
if (topPos > 500) {
  $(scrollTop).css("opacity", "1");

} else {
  $(scrollTop).css("opacity", "0");
}

 }); // scroll END

 //Click event to scroll to top
 $(scrollTop).click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 800);
  return false;

 }); 

  });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the runnable snippet at the bottom of the page here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231811/how-can-i-add-text-in-my-scroll-to-top-button-which-already-has-an-icon-in-it

Comment: nope, not working.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle as done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766686/anchor-tags-onclick-isnt-executing-a-simple-jquery-function-in-jsfiddle

Comment: console.log topPos. What value is topPos for your screen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Xteripus/pen/NWRpJEr here

Comment: well its working here but not working on my local :\

Comment: console.log topPos not working it says unexpected identifier

Comment: my jquery works on live. my problem is it only works on mobile not both desktop and mobile.

Comment: thank you for your efforts, but it seems like its not gonna work and i have missed something. i have looked for it almost 2 hours now but i  have to check it again. Thanks again.

Comment: Someone might come along and view this in a "desktop" browser and know exactly what the problem is https://codepen.io/Xteripus/pen/NWRpJEr What debugging tools do you use?  It might help if you described your desktop machine.

Comment: I am using vscode with live server addon on windows 10 machine. i am using all browsers but mainly i am tesing on opera.